# How to avoid a correct instruction to be detected as error in NetBeans?

Tags: javascript, node.js, netbeans, ide, socket.io

I'm developing a little socket.io and node.js system using NetBeans 7.2 as my IDE.

I'm finding myself running with an error highlight every time I write a perfect correct instruction like:

```
io.sockets.in(channel_id).emit('new user', data);
```

Precisely, the **".in"** part is what bothers NetBeans (I guess because 'in' is a reserved javascript word). The error I'm getting is **"missing name after . operator"**

Is there any way I can disable this particular syntax error? (I want the other errors to be highlighted, so I don't want to disable all error checking)

Comment: This is terrible, but how about wrapping it in `eval`?

Comment: Terrible! You just said it! I don't want to mess correct code just because of the IDE

Comment: Oh well, fight something terrible like NetBeans with something terrible, that's the way :P Anyway, you can keep it as long as you have to debug. Annoying, yes, but nothing else comes to my mind. And the code wouldn't be so "messed": evaluating like that is safe as long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks @elmigranto , that worked like a charm (and I'm ashamed to not having thought about array notation). I'm newbie here, how can I accept your answer when you made it as a comment?

Comment: That's comment, not answer. But now you can.

Comment: That is not a correct instruction, NetBeans it right - `in` is a JavaScript operator and cannot be used as an identifier

Comment: @Bergi, well, [it can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FReserved_Words#Reserved_word_usage).

Comment: @elmigranto: Oh, right. I thought that the dot notation were restricted to valid identifiers

Comment: @MaxArt So, being NetBeans something terrible by your words, which IDE would you recomment for PHP + Node.JS development?

Comment: @antonienko If forced to use an IDE, I'd use Eclipse, which actually is more or less the same thing without the Oracle stuff. But really, my usual IDE is Notepad++...

Comment: @antonienko I use Sublime Text 2 and gonna check out cloud9 some time (you can install it on localhost and there are some neat features; could be awesome).

Comment: @elmigranto Sublime Text looks awesome. I've read somewhere that cloud9 on localhost misses some features, because third party integration is not part of the open source codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing object's property like this should work:

```js
io.sockets['in']
```